# Let $(X,\epsilon)$ be a measurable space. Show $\mu: \epsilon \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is a measure given three conditions.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,\epsilon)$ be a measure space and $\mu: \epsilon \rightarrow [0, \infty]$.

Suppose $\mu$ satisfies $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for disjoint $A,B$ and $\mu(\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(B_n)$ for a decresing sequence $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, $ B_{n+1} \subseteq B_n$.

Also suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$.

I want to show this implies $\mu$ is a measure.

The only thing to prove is $\mu(\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$ for any sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of disjoint sets.

However, I can't find any way to write $\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ as $\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let
$$
B_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k^c=\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\Big)^c,\quad n\geq 1,
$$
and use
$$
\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n =\bigcup_{n\geq 1} B_n^c=\Big(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} B_n\Big)^c.
$$

Comment: Thanks ! - Should I then write $\Big(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} B_n\Big)^c$ as $X / \Big(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} B_n\Big)$ in $\mu$ ?

Comment: Yes. And note that to move on from here we need to use that $\mu$ is finite.

Comment: But then I get a constant in my equation, namely $\mu(X) < \infty$, that I can't seem to get rid off.

Comment: By assumption $\mu(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} B_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(B_n)=\mu(X)-\sum_{n\geq 1} \mu(A_n)$, so that $\mu(X)$ cancels.

Comment: Yeah, I got it myself a minute ago :D ... And we can say $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(X) - \mu(\cup_{k=1}^n A_k) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(X) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\cup_{k=1}^n A_k)$$ because $$\mu(\cup_{k=1}^n A_k)$$ is bounded, monotone and there convergent.

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$